# how to use json_encode function of an array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I would like to select a specific line of an object that have been created using json_encode function from a php array.

```html
  while($locations=$req->fetch()){
    $t = $locations->titre;
    $la = $locations->latitude;
    $lo = $locations->longitude;
    $typ = $locations->type;
    $ep = $locations->couleur;
    $matrice[$i] = array($t, $la, $lo, $ep);
    $i=$i+1;
  }
```

```js
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($matrice); ?>;
locations[0] = ['ma position actuelle', 0, 0, 0];

//console.log(Object.keys(locations));
//console.log(locations);

var centerLat=0.0, centerLong=0.0;
for (var i=1; i<Object.keys(locations).length; i++) {
  centerLat+=locations[i][1];
 centerLong+=locations[i][2];
}
```

I would like to select the second and the third element of "locations" but the syntax inside the loop is wrong. Does anyone has an idea.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome.  Please read [ask], particularly how to create an [mcve].  Right now, we have to _guess_ at the data structure.  Further, I'm pretty sure you're confusing the matter with all the tags - you likely are just wanting `javascript`, and if you could provide us with the value of `locations`, it'd be far simpler....

Comment: Is `location` an object or an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Try `for (var i in locations) {` instead.

Comment: json_encode results in a string.  Your next line is assuming it's an array.  Are you sure you didn't mean json_decode?

Answer (score 0):

First you should do:

```
var locations = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($matrice); ?>);
```

Then `console.log(locations.toString());` to check your data

After, I think you're looking for [Array.prototype.unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to add elements at the beginning of the array:

```
locations.unshift(['ma position actuelle', 0, 0, 0]);
```

(`locations[0] = ['ma position actuelle', 0, 0, 0]` just replace first item of the array)

then change you for loop

```
for (var i=1; i<Object.keys(locations).length; i++)
```

for

```
var i = 1, ln = locations.length;
for (i;i<ln;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access any item in an JSONArray (or any Array) in JS like this:

```
object[i]
```

In your example, if you wanna get the second and third element:

```
for (...) {
  var longitude = locations[i][1];
  var latitude = locations[i][2];
}
```

But, I suggest that you use keys and make JSONObjects instead of just JSONArrays, like this:

```
  $locations = array();

  while($locations=$req->fetch()){

    $location = array(
      'titre' => $locations->titre,
      'latitude' => $locations->latitude,
      'longitude' => $locations->longitude,
      ... etc
    );

    $locations[] = $location;

  }
```

That way you'll end up with a nice JSONArray filled with JSONObjects and you can call them from JS like this:

```
//locations is a JSONArray
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($matrice); ?>; 
//locations[0] is a JSONObject
var latitude = locations[0].latitude;
var latitude = locations[0].longitude;
```